# eth1 slow to come up

Tags: networking

Hi when i disconnect the cable from eth1 and reconnect it takes around 30 seconds for the interface to come up and be pingable.

We have checked the cisco port and we have portfast enabled.

We did enable ubuntu to use VLANs.

Eth1 is statically configured.

Any ideas what might cause this delay?

Thanks for your suggestions,

kam270

Comment: How did you configure ubuntu to use VLANs? I'd look to see if portfast is kicking in on the switch. Reconnect cable and do `show spanning-tree interface INTERFACE` in IOS see if the port goes into forwarding state FWD right away as expected to rule switch out

Comment: The vlan was configured using vlan package. My  /etc/network/interfaces
#add VLAN 200 on eth1
 auto eth1.200
 iface eth1.200 inet static
  address 192.168.100.192
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  vlan-raw-device eth1

The port has portfast enabled and shows the correct LAN0200            Desg LIS 19        128.32   P2p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your problem portfast is not kicking in.  *Desg **LIS** 19 128.32 P2p* port doesn't forward packets in the Listening state for 15sec, after which it'll go to LRN learning state for another 15sec before finally going into FWD forwarding state. Are you not running RSTP? In any case looks like it's a Cisco question and not Ubuntu

Comment: Ahh will investigate the CISCO issue more deeply. Thanks